# On ARIMA and its implementation

Tags: references, arima, arma, c++

I am interested in ARMA/ARIMA models. First off, is there any material online about how to identify such models? It is done via acf and pacf, but I find the material I found online somewhat misleading. I would like to have a set of rule of thumbs I can use for that.

Secondly, do you know of any C++ library, equivalent to R for time series?

Finally, is it possible to include dependency across different time series? For example, suppose we know that series $\{x\}_n$ depends upon series $\{y\}_n$. How would I include this when using ARIMA models?

Comment: It seems that you are asking several independent questions at once in this post. I'd recommend that you move at least the last question to a separate post, as this keeps the site tidy and makes questions and answers easier to find in the future!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes. See http://otexts.com/fpp/8/  Using the ACF and PACF to identify models is very out-of-date and there are much better methods available. Use the AIC, for example.
2. The R function `arima()` uses C code and it is open-source.
3. If the dependency goes in both directions, you might consider a VAR or VARIMA model. If $x$ depends on $y$, but not vice-versa, you might use a regression with ARIMA errors, or a transfer-function model.

Comment: could you possibly provide a reference for VAR and VARIMA?

Comment: Try Reinsel's book: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0387406190/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=0387406190&linkCode=as2&tag=prorobjhyn-20

Answer (score 0):

I found this reference online that I think is a good introduction that may be helpful but is not a full  tutorial on how to identify them.

http://www.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm

As I find common wikipedia gives a nice introduction with some useful links.  I find the reference list too short.  That could be improved a lot.  Here is the link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average

I found this presentation that I think is particularly good and meets most of your needs.

http://www.stats24x7.com/9ARIMAMODELINGOFTIMESERIES.pdf